# Time in Left Join - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to generate a dynamic chart with a steady timeline, therefore I need to add additional time (minutes) to the x-axis.
I need 2 columns. Column 1 (time) shows every minute of the day from a table which simply has a time column listing from 00:00 to 23:59 (the example table only has 20 mins). I'm trying to join this with the results from the 'log' table. The query will filter which machine 'name' I'm looking at, eg Machine 'name' '1'. Then list when this machine changed state alongside the 1440 minutes from the 'TimeMins' table. I hope that helps? 
 Ultimately, I have a dynamic chart which shows the state changes for a machine throughout the whole day. The 'time' column will set the x-axis for the graph giving a steady timeline

Unfortunately I can't get it to join properly. Maybe there's another way or can someone crack the problem please?

The result should be similar to...

```
time       state
00:00       null (or zero)
00:01       null
00:02        1
00:03       null
00:04       null
00:05        0
00:06       null
00:07        1
```

etc. A value for every minute of the day, whether there was a result in 'log' for that minute or not.

Very much appreciated. Have been on this for over 2 days.

Here is the SQLfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f91a0/2

Thanks.
Jamie.

Comment: I edited but the page didn't update how I wrote it. 2 columns. 'Time' and 'State'. Thanks.

Comment: Strawberry please see my added comments below. Your help would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Fair enough. Have edited it thanks.

Comment: This is a simple LEFT JOIN - but you really don't need this utility table. It would be quicker and simpler to handle the logic of missing results in your php loop.

Comment: Thanks Strawberry. Does anyone here want to help me here? Simple as it apparently is, I can't work it out. PHP loop wouldn't work because I need it to generate an xml for my chart.

Comment: "PHP loop wouldn't work because I need it to generate an xml for my chart" Eh? What are you using to build your chart?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner select.

In the example bellow I'm using 3.

```
select name, beginning, ending - beginning as seconds from (
  select a.name, a.ts as beginning, (
    select min(b.ts) 
    from log b 
    where b.ts > a.ts and a.name = b.name and b.state = 0
  ) as ending
  from log a 
  where a.state = 1
) c
order by beginning;
```

2nd is providing the start and end for each machine

the 1st is wrapping the 2nd and it's just calculating seconds for each run and sorting the result by start

The 3rd is trying to find next row when machine stops after the a.ts started and state 0 with the same name (to match the same machine)

```
select min(b.ts) 
    from log b 
    where b.ts > a.ts and a.name = b.name and b.state = 0
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f91a0/14

Comment: Thanks Richard but that isn't quite what I'm looking to do. My poor explanation. I need 2 columns. Column 1 (time) shows every minute of the day from a table which simply has a time column listing from 00:00 to 23:59. I'm trying to join this with the results from the 'log' table. The query will filter which machine 'name' I'm looking at, eg '1'. Then list when this machine changed state alongside the 1440 minutes from the 'TimeMins' table. I hope that helps?

Comment: Ultimately, I have a dynamic chart which shows the state changes for a machine throughout the whole day. The 'time' column will set the x-axis for the graph giving a steady timeline.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not advocating this as a solution (and even with this method, there are surely more optimal ways of writing this query), but just by way of illustration...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `log`;
CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ts` datetime NOT NULL,
  `state` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `log` VALUES 
(20,1,'2016-05-16 00:03:02',1),
(21,1,'2016-05-16 00:04:03',0),
(22,2,'2016-05-16 00:04:28',1),
(23,2,'2016-05-16 00:06:45',0),
(25,1,'2016-05-16 00:14:50',1),
(26,2,'2016-05-16 00:15:35',1);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `TimeMins`;

CREATE TABLE `TimeMins` (
t time PRIMARY KEY 
);

INSERT INTO `TimeMins` VALUES 
('00:00:00'),
('00:01:00'),
('00:02:00'),
('00:03:00'),
('00:04:00'),
('00:05:00'),
('00:06:00'),
('00:07:00'),
('00:08:00'),
('00:09:00'),
('00:10:00'),
('00:11:00'),
('00:12:00'),
('00:13:00'),
('00:14:00'),
('00:15:00'),
('00:16:00'),
('00:17:00'),
('00:18:00'),
('00:19:00'),
('00:20:00');

SELECT a.*
     , b.id
     , b.name
     , b.state 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(DATE(l.ts),' ',t.t) i 
                  FROM log l
                     , timemins t
     ) a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN log b 
    ON DATE_FORMAT(b.ts,'%Y%m%d%h%i') = DATE_FORMAT(a.i,'%Y%m%d%h%i');
+---------------------+------+------+-------+
| i                   | id   | name | state |
+---------------------+------+------+-------+
| 2016-05-16 00:00:00 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2016-05-16 00:01:00 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2016-05-16 00:02:00 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2016-05-16 00:03:00 |   20 | 1    |     1 |
| 2016-05-16 00:04:00 |   21 | 1    |     0 |
| 2016-05-16 00:04:00 |   22 | 2    |     1 |
| 2016-05-16 00:05:00 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2016-05-16 00:06:00 |   23 | 2    |     0 |
| 2016-05-16 00:07:00 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2016-05-16 00:08:00 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2016-05-16 00:09:00 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2016-05-16 00:10:00 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2016-05-16 00:11:00 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2016-05-16 00:12:00 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2016-05-16 00:13:00 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2016-05-16 00:14:00 |   25 | 1    |     1 |
| 2016-05-16 00:15:00 |   26 | 2    |     1 |
| 2016-05-16 00:16:00 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2016-05-16 00:17:00 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2016-05-16 00:18:00 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2016-05-16 00:19:00 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
| 2016-05-16 00:20:00 | NULL | NULL |  NULL |
+---------------------+------+------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks Strawberry but your solution doesn't seem to give the results on your result table. There are minutes missing in between the joined times.

Comment: Strawberry, it is very close but the results are not in time order. It shows 00:03:00 as the first line but 00:00:00 should be at the start. I did try to alter your code to order by time but was unable to. Could you please have another look. Thanks.

Comment: Well, maybe I'll get back to you in September ;-)